# Multiple Choice – DropdownMenus

Tags: php, jquery, sql, wordpress, forms

I have a (wordpress)-website for searching/finding  regional events „intern“ on my site. All events have one or more categories. I.E. Category of the location. Category of the Weekday. Category of the theme of the event etc..

With the standard dropdown-menu wp_dropdown_categories($args) the user is be able to choice always only one categorie „or“ another. My wish is a multiple choice. If the user choice „location“ (i. e. „Berlin“) and also the Date, i want to show only the events which are in both caegories. For that i need handy hints for a way to do so.

What would be a good way?

(i know to create a form with php and i know also jquery/ajax and sql a little bit.)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use "In" Operator for selecting the events with multiple categories LIke in the below queries

```
Select * from events
Where Categories in ('location','Weekday');
```